# Writing strend(s, t) (check if `s` ends with `t`) using pointers

Tags: c, string, algorithm, pointers

I am writing an implementation of `strend(s, t)`, which checks if a string `s` ends with string `t`.

Example, if -

```
char s[] = "abcdefoo";
char t[] = "foo";
```

then, `strend(s, t)` is true because `"abcdefoo"` ends with`"foo"`.

but, if -

```
char s[] = "acefooD";
char t[] = "foo";
```

then, `strend(s, t)` is false because `"acefooD"` does not end with`"foo"`.

Here is my code. It always returns `0` (false). I cant understand why.

```
int strend(char *s, char *t)
{
    char *i;

    i = s + strlen(s) - strlen(t);
    while (*i++ == *t++ != '\0')
        ;
    if (*i == '\0')
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Why isn't it working?

PS: This is an exercise in K&R2.

Comment: `(*i++ == *t++ != '\0')` should be `(*i++ == *t++)`

Comment: I don't see the relation between K&R and C++. (hint, hint)

Comment: @glglgl But there is a relation between pointers and c++.

Comment: May I also suggest putting in an empty set of braces for good styling(even if this is just an exercise)? While that loop is technically correct it could easily be confusing for someone maintaining the code as is. With as esoteric as this operation is, it would be common to assume that semicolon was a typo. Removing that semi-colon REALLY changes the logic of the program. Remember: It is never a bad thing to be too explicit about your code ordering, whether it's using `()` for operation orders or `{}` to explicitly define code blocks.

Comment: @IanT.Small **Point noted sir.**

Comment: You might want to check if `s` is shorter than `t` before dereferencing `i`.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Thanks. That will catch exceptions.

Comment: Once you've run strlen() on both strings (confirming that they are both properly NUL terminated) and used the results to confirm that s is longer than t ... then why can't you use something like strncmp() passing it pointers to t and to the offset within s were the t-length substring of s would start?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The condition

```
while (*i++ == *t++ != '\0')
```

does not do what you expect it to do. It evaluates `*i++ == *t++`, yielding 0 or 1, and checks whether that value is different from 0, so that's equivalent to

```
while (*i++ == *t++)
```

Then, when `s` ends with `t`, you have incremented `i` past the 0-terminator.

Check that `*i != 0` first,

```
while (*i && *i++ == *t++);
```

to stop at the 0-terminator. But that will fail if there is a mismatch at the last character before the 0-terminator, since then both pointers will still be incremented, and `i` points to the terminator, so
 better use

```
while (*i && *i == *t++) i++;
```

to only increment `i` when the two pointed-to characters match.

Comment: @ShuklaSannidhya Not quite, see the last part.

Comment: @DanielFischer In which case does it fail?

Comment: @ShuklaSannidhya The `while(*i && *i++ == *t++);` will fail if there is a mismatch at the last character before the 0-terminator, but not before, e.g. `"abcfob"` and `"foo"`. At the last character, `*i++ == *t++` will compare `'b'` to `'o'`, but increment the pointer(s) although thy are unequal, so then `i` still points to the terminator after the loop.

Answer (score 2):

try `while ( *t && *i++ == *t++ )`.

```
int strend(char *s, char *t)
{
    char *i;

    i = s + strlen(s) - strlen(t);
    while (*i && *i++ == *t++ )
        ;
    if (*i == '\0')
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

*I tried it and it works.*

Comment: @ShuklaSannidhya It returns `1` here.

Comment: Yeah, it works. I wrote `while (*i & *i++ == *t++ )` I forgot one ampersand (`&`), thats why it wasn't working.

Comment: Doesn't work for `strend("abcfob", "foo")`, I didn't notice that immediately either.